# Repeater with different culture per item

Tags: asp.net, repeater, culture

I have a repeater control which displays pricing, the currency symbol should be shown depending on the country of the specific person.

Generally, I'd just do something like:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CheapestLesson", "{0:C}")
```

However, this will take the current page culture. Is there any way to override the culture when handling the onItemDataBound event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a different culture when the string is formatted if you use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx) of `String.Format`:

```
<%# String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CheapestLesson")) %>
```

All `CultureInfo` objects implement the `IFormatProvider` interface, so if you use this overload of `String.Format` you can override the current culture with a specific culture only for this formatting.

Comment: I got an error saying Type 'CultureInfo' is not defined. I fixed it with full namespace System.Globalization.CultureInfo like: `<%# String.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CheapestLesson")) %>` Thanks for the solution!